# Xcode 6: Autolayout for button will auto resize and position problems

Tags: autolayout, xcode6

I'm having some problems with Auto-Layout in Xcode 6 Beta, I have a ViewController and three buttons, want and show like how it look like on the storyboard. Means the fix the "height" between "PROCEED WITH FACEBOOK" and bottom, and other 2 button will depend on the "PROCEED WITH FACEBOOK" to reposition.

Another problem i meet is, when i preview it, the button will auto scale. example: iphone 4-inch, the "SIGNUP VIA EMAIL" will be smaller. when go to iphone 5.5inch, "SIGNUP VIA EMAIL" will be auto scale to big.

thanks for help![image]

Answer (score 0):

just found out the solution from others side.
because i mistake to add the "fix height" from "Login" with top, so it will make one of the button will auto size when the screen size is different.